# swift whats the difference between these protocols

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've seen protocols been declared in two ways, but I don't get the difference.

Ex1:

```
protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate {
    func controller(controller: AddItemViewController, didAddItem: String)
}
```

Ex2:

```
protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func controller(controller: AddItemViewController, didAddItem: String)
}
```

So whats the difference?

Comment: why did you delete your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127906/swift-go-back-from-vc3-to-vc1-and-also-pass-data/32128063#32128063 ? I was just about to post a complete sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or
>   enumerations) by adding the `class` keyword to a protocol’s inheritance
>   list. The class keyword must always appear first in a protocol’s
>   inheritance list, before any inherited protocols:
>
> ```
> protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: class, SomeInheritedProtocol {
> // class-only protocol definition goes here }
> ```

Note:

> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s
>   requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference
>   semantics rather than value semantics.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to declare a variable like this :

```
var aVar : AddItemViewControllerDelegate?
```

you have to do :

```
protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func controller(controller: AddItemViewController, didAddItem: String)
}
```

Comment: eg: weak var delegate: AddItemViewController?  ?

Comment: well, it's just a example, not guarantee to be controllerDelegate. Sometimes, you just want a pointer to a class that obey a delegate.